# FTP automation on windows not working

Tags: xml, eclipse, ant, ftp

I have my script as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Getting from FTP" default="info" basedir=".">

   <target name="info">
    <property name="testfolder" value="My\Test\Folder\Path" />
      <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
      <echo>Java version: ${ant.java.version}</echo>
      <echo>Ant Version: ${ant.version}</echo>
      <echo>Base Dir: "${basedir}"</echo>
      <mkdir dir="${testfolder}\ant-test"/>
       <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.jar" />
      </classpath>
      <ftp action="get"
        server="my.server.location.somewhere"
        userid="username"
        password="password"
        remotedir="/path/on/my/server"
        verbose="yes"
        >
        <fileset dir="${testfolder}\ant-test">
            <include name="**\*" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
   </target>
</project>
```

I am writing the file on eclipse, and putting up the commons-net-3.3.jar file in my workspace folder. Here, it is AutomateDownload. But, when I run the script, I get this error:

```
Buildfile: mydrive\on_server\my_workspace\ftpauto\AutomateDownload\build.xml
info:
     [echo] Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!
     [echo] Java version: 1.8
     [echo] Ant Version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
     [echo] Base Dir: "mydrive\on_server\my_workspace\ftpauto\AutomateDownload"

BUILD FAILED
mydrive\on_server\my_workspace\ftpauto\AutomateDownload\build.xml:11: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

It worked on my local machine, as I had kept the .jar file in my lib folder of the ANT_HOME. It worked perfectly. But now when I run it on my server machine, the error is faced by me. Can anyone help with the problem I am suffering, and also could you tell me in detail, what really is the problem? Why did I face this kind of problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ANT task called "classpath". That is why ANT is throwing an error.

I suspect what you're trying to do is create a path reference?

```
  <path id="proj.path">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.jar" />
  </path>
```

But... The **ftp** task doesn't support classpath references... So you are best advised to place dependency jars in the "$HOME/.ant/lib" directory.

A trick I use is to download and install dependencies using an special ANT target:

```
<target name="install-dependencies">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/commons-net.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-net/commons-net/3.3/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
</target>
```

The target only needs to be run once on each build machine

```
$ ant install-dependencies
```